# How to append image and anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core

I am writing a function where I dynamically create various divs, containing an image and an anchor tag and then append them to an existing div.
Now, they're being appended alright, the problem, is that something is wrong with both the images and the anchor tags.

The anchors cannot be clicked on. They are just showing as blue text, not a link. And the image is not being displayed. The latter can't be caused because of incorrect file path.

[image]

Here is the Javascript/JQuery part:

```
 $.ajax({
          
            url: 'Home/GetComments',
            data: { postId: id },
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    var div = document.createElement("Div");
                    div.setAttribute('class', 'comment');

                    var image = document.createElement("img");
                    var imageSource = "~/images/" + result[i].userImage;
                    image.src = imageSource;
                    div.appendChild(image);

                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    var linkText = document.createTextNode(result[i].userName);
                    a.appendChild(linkText);
                    a.setAttribute('asp-action', 'UserProfile');
                    a.setAttribute('asp-route-name', result[i].userName);
                    
                    div.appendChild(a);

                    $("#" + stringId).append(div);
                }      },
        });
```

And this is the response from the controller:

```
 public JsonResult GetComments(long postId)
        {
            var comment1 = new Comment()
            {      
                Id = 1,
                UserName = "User1",
                UserImage = "Udklipre.PNG"          
            };
            var comment2 = new Comment()
            {
                Id = 2,
                UserName = "User2",
                UserImage = "Udklipre.PNG"
            };

            Comment[] comments = { comment1, comment2 };
            return Json(comments);
        }
```

Comment: This is just an intelligent guess, I am not an ASP person. Are you sure `asp-action` and `asp-route-name` attributes work if you create the elements *dinamically*? Usually, when you write templates with special markup such as ASP custom attributes,  it gets preprocessed and lots of frontend code is generated, so the actual HTML and JS source is different, than what you see in the editor. As you are just creating the elements dinamically here, it might be, that the corresponding framework related code to wire up the actions is missing. Sorry if this does not help at all.

Comment: Actually, it did help. It made me look on the internet, and look for an example of someone trying to dynamically create anchor-tags with asp-action. And I wasnt able to find it. But I realised that there was a way to do what i wanted without the asp-action.

Comment: Doing this solved the issue: var hrefText = "/Home/UserProfile?name=" + result[i].userName;         a.setAttribute('href', hrefText);

Comment: Nice and easy! :) I guess all ASP does is generate the actual links with the proper URLs according to your routing config. But that's just another guess. It's worth checking though, just to dispell the magic behind it. :) However, take note, that in this case, you are hard coding the URL, which might or not might not cause bugs in the future.

Comment: When you say it might cause bugs, what do you mean? The username is being passed to the parameter in the action as it should. So what else is there to consider?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I wasn't very helpful there. I mean if the routing configuration should change (controller, action or parameter), you have to manually update this URL. If the project is in development, this might happen. If it is in production, it is unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Anchor tags need a hyperlink reference (`href`) in order for the browser to understand them as clickable, which is why you see `href="#"` so frequently. If you don't want the hash in the url when you click on it, you can use `href="javascript: void(0)"` instead.

```
a.setAttribute('href', '#');
```

Comment: If I do that, the link still doesn't work as intended. When I click on it, it is supposed to activate the Userprofile action in the controller. That doesnt happen.

Comment: it sounds like it already wasn't working. post a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the 'href' attribute to make it look clickable. Here you have two options:

```
a.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
// or
a.setAttribute('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
```

Comment: The link still doesn't work as intended. It is supposed to lead to the UserProfile action, not a page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a worked demo(tag-helper such as `asp-action` cannot be used in ajax):

HomeController:

```
public IActionResult Add() {
            return View();
        }
        public JsonResult GetComments(long postId) {
            var comment1 = new Comment()
            {
                Id = 1,
                UserName = "User1",
                UserImage = "gif.gif"
            };
            var comment2 = new Comment()
            {
                Id = 2,
                UserName = "User2",
                UserImage = "t-shirt.jpg"
            };

            Comment[] comments = { comment1, comment2 };
            return Json(comments);
        }
        public ActionResult UserProfile(string username) {
            return View("Add");
        }
```

Add.cshtml:

```
 <button onclick="add()">add</button>
<div id="stringId"></div>
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function add() {
            $.ajax({

                url: 'GetComments',
                data: { postId: 1 },
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                        var div = document.createElement("Div");
                        div.setAttribute('class', 'comment');
                        var image = document.createElement("img");
                        var imageSource = "/images/" + result[i].userImage;
                        image.src = imageSource;
                        div.appendChild(image);

                        var a = document.createElement('a');
                        var linkText = document.createTextNode(result[i].userName);
                        a.appendChild(linkText);
                        a.href = "UserProfile?username=" + result[i].userName;
                        div.appendChild(a);

                        $("#stringId").append(div);
                    }
                },
            });
        }
    </script>

}
```

result:
[image]